# Properly display all outputs in a Shiny dashboard after bookmarking/restoration

Tags: r, shiny

When you do restore a Shiny session using the native Bookmark functionality in a dashboard with multiple `tabItems`, you fall on the one which was active at the moment of the bookmarking (legit). However, outputs (tab, plots, ...) from other `tabItems()` are not refreshed/recalculated until you actually click on them and be displayed in the browser. Is there a way to also during the restoration process recalculate those undisplayed outputs?

One possible non-elegant work around would be to have at the end of the `onRestored()` a bunch of `updateTabItems()` for each existing tabItems we want to display properly.

Comment: You could try the `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` option in [`outputOptions`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/outputOptions.html). However, it is not well documented and a bit tricky to get it to work/where to place the `outputOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that could be interested, a general answer to this general question and as @starja suggested, is to use `suspendWhenHidden = TRUE`.

The idea is quite simple: by default each `output` object of a Shiny application is not run until it is requested to be displayed within the browser (`suspendWhenHidden = TRUE`). To change that behavior, simply add the following line of code in your server (not sure there is a specific place):

```
  outputOptions(output, "my_output_name", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Therefore, after a session restauration (bookmarking), even if you land on tab "B", every output of tab "A" with `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` will be executed, therefore leading your reactive expressions depending on those outputs to be "refreshed" and correctly ran/displayed within tab "B".